# How to sum hours based on criteria in to tables (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having to "tables" i Excel

```
     A        B      C      D        E       F
1          Category               Project  Hours
2  Project    C1     C2             P1       10
3    P1        x                    P2       20
4    P2               x             P3       30
5    P3        x      x
6    P4        x
```

A2:C6 shows a list of project. Each project belongs to one og more categories
E2:F4 shows the time spent on each project

I'm looking for a way to sum the time spent in each category. The answer is obvious (40h and 50h), but I can't figure out how to construct a working formula, that will provide the answer

```
      H           I
1  Category   Sum Hours
2     C1          40
3     C2          50
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

SUMPRODUCT() seems to be good choice for this case. If you allow results columns with slight modification, it becomes easier for the formula.
Enter this formula in H2 then copy to I2.

```
   =SUMPRODUCT((B$2=H$1)*(B$3:B$6="x")*($F$2:$F$5))
```

[image: Snapshot showing data and results]

I have combined `INDEX, MATCH` with `SUMPRODUCT` To take care of Pnumbers. Revised Formula to enter in `H2` is:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((B$2=H$1)*(B$3:B$6="x")*($F$2:$F$5)))*((INDEX($A$3:$A$6,MATCH($E2,$A$3:$A$6))=$E2)*1)
```

Next step would be to include error trapping by `IFERROR`.

**EDIT**
Incorporating `IFERROR` formula is.

```
=IFERROR((SUMPRODUCT((B$2=H$1)*(B$3:B$6="x")*($F$2:$F$5)))*((INDEX($A$3:$A$6,MATCH($E2,$A$3:$A$6))=$E2)*1),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for hour answer. It works if because P1-P3 in A3-A5 are listed in the same order as P1-P3 in E2-E4. This won't always be the case. So I need a solution where the Pnumbers in column A og E are part of the formula. And that's what make it a conundrum :-)

Comment: I think it is possible to include Pnumbers part of the formula by wrapping them in COUNTIFS function. Principal approach would be to apply COUNTIFS on range $A$3:$A$6 taking criteria from $E$2:$E$4 in OR condition. I am trying to figure out the syntax. But to me it appears correct approach.

Comment: Please look into revised formula incorporating Pnumbers criteria. I have just now edited my answer.

Comment: @skkakkar your cell references in your edited formula need to be updated.  Looks like your D3:D6 should be B3:B6. your D2 should be B2 and you J1 shouldbe be H1

Comment: @TorstenBachSchrøder  is the horizontal adjusting formula working for you or do you need one that copies down?

Comment: @Forward Ed I shall look into it as per your advice. Thanks for your kind involvement. However, I find OP answer better then mine.

Comment: @Forward Ed I copied from a wrong cell in a hurry. Corrections have been incorporated in the latest edit. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @skkakkar I have made the same mistake in the past.  Just thought I would point it out for others that may stumble on this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of `SUMIF`. You can enter `=SUMIF(B3:B6;"x";$F2:$F5)` in your I2 and modify accordingly for the other category. If you apply the formulae next to one another instead of below one another, you can copy the formula across.

I recommend you change the sheet in the following way:

```
    A        B        C        D          E       F
1           =SUMIF1 =SUMIF2            Project  Hours
2  Project    C1       C2    Hours        P1       10
3    P1        x             =VLOOKUP     P2       20
4    P2                 x    =VLOOKUP     P3       30
5    P3        x        x    =VLOOKUP
6    P4        x             =VLOOKUP
```

Where the `SUMIF1` formula is `=SUMIF(B3:B6;"x";$D3:$D6)` and `SUMIF2` is that one copied over. This will work for whatever labels you choose. The `VLOOKUP` formula in `D3` is `=VLOOKUP(A3;$E$2:$F$4;2;FALSE)`. Note that this will have a `#NA` for D6 since there are no hours for P4. Just fix that and you have a relatively general solution.

Comment: I should have been a little more specific. I cannot be sure, that the category "C1" will be listed in column B or that category "C2" will be listed in column C. The category "C1" might be in any of the columns B, C or D. Thats whats make everything a little triggy...

Comment: I recommend doing the sum hours calculation in row 1 (just above the category label). That way the category labels can be anything and the `SUMIF` will still work. Also, I see in the comment to the other answer you mention that the list of project hours in `E2:F5` won't always be in the same order. As long as they are unique, you can use `VLOOKUP` to match them.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon very inspirtional answers from [skkakker](/questions/tagged/skkakker) and [chthonicdaemon](/questions/tagged/chthonicdaemon) I came up with this solution, which Works. Thanks!

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$6,$E$2:$E$4,INDEX($B$3:$C$6,0,MATCH($H2,$B$2:$C$2,0)),"x"),$F$2:$F$4)`

Comment: We are happy that we could be a part of your efforts to find a solution to this problem.